# When did the Jewish people knead the dough that they took out of Egypt?

Tags: history, matzah, yetziat-mitzrayim, kneading-lash

The Jewish people took dough out of Egypt with them. 
See [Shemos 12 (39)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9873#showrashi=true) which says

> “They baked the dough that they had taken out of Egypt as unleavened
>   cakes, for it had not leavened, for they were driven out of Egypt, and
>   they could not tarry, and also, they had not made provisions for
>   themselves.”

and 
[Shemos 12 (34)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9873#showrashi=true)

> “The people picked up their dough when it was not yet leavened, their
>   leftovers bound in their garments on their shoulders.”

Rashi says:

> **when it was not yet leavened:** The Egyptians did not permit them to tarry long enough for it to leaven.
>
> **their leftovers:** The remaining matzah and bitter herbs.

My question is when was this dough made (was it the leftovers of the dough for the matzos that they ate with the korban Pesach).

related - my question last year: [How did our forefathers bake the dough they took out of Egypt? Would it qualify as matzo now?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57122/how-did-our-forefathers-bake-the-dough-they-took-out-of-egypt-would-it-qualify)

Comment: The simple answer @Avrhom Yitzchok is this. At first they decided to rely on hashem and not make any "tsado" for their way. At the "last minute"  they got cold feet and they changed their minds and decided to make dough for their journey.  If they would have succeeded they would not have been able to go out. So hashem in his mercy made sure there would be "chiposon" and they would be thrown out before the dough was ready so they still had the zchus of their earlier mind which was not to make dough. It is a deep vort but still true and  correct.

Comment: @newcomer - I like it. Is it your own or can you please source it?

Comment: It is not my own, but something I alway say must have some source somewhere will have to look @Avrohom Yitzchok

Comment: ,    
       
       ,    
       

     
   
 
        

    
      ! , 
   
    
 
Looking in my book I dont have the source,  but it adds on. To teach you that if at first you have the right attitude even if when it comes to it you get cold feet,  hashem helps you to succeed.

Comment: @newcomer - You might like to post it as an answer; but you will probably  get requests for sources.